# Can't connect to my private cluster using kubectl (Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp )

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

i have 2 clusters same config, till yesterday i was able to connect to both of them, but today i was not able to connect to one of them, all apps are working fine, i just get this error when using kubectl

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp IP:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond
```

i tried scaling up and down my cluster from the interface ( the scaling works but still i can't use kubectl)

can someone help please?

Comment: check your context which kubectl is working or using, hope that pointing first to k8s servers only

Comment: it's not a context issue , this is error apeared on 1 of my 8 clusters , and its configuration is identical to another , when i switch between other cluster i have no issues , i tried resetting the config file using ```gcloud container clusters get-credentials clustername --zone zoneid --project projectid``` , i also compared certificate and firewall rules nothing has changed

Comment: Looks like something it blocking the connection.

I would suggest looking in the proxy logs to see if it reports any start up errors.

Comment: Are you able to ping, nmap, traceroute, route, etc.  your current public IP?

Comment: i can't telnet to allowed port 443 witch used to work , and still working on my second one , (destination unreachable for tracert)

Comment: Are you using private cluster with public endpoint access? it's enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was network conflict with the docker bridge network , basically i was using dockers default bridge network as my GKE endpoint , so when i installed docker on my deployment machine (to automatically build images and push them) i lost the connection to this kubernetes cluster.

So all i had to do was disable the bridge network , and i got my connection back to this cluster